# How do I parse 宋耀如一家用过早餐?

Tags: translation

This sentence is from the 3-rd grade 语文 book I'm studying (the exact pages are [here](http://www.nanshansi123.com/kewen/sannianjishangce/1200.html)):

> 一个星期天，**宋耀如一家用过早餐**，准备到一位朋友家去。

It says "One Sunday, [something], ready to go to a friends house."

**Question**: How do I parse 宋耀如一家用过早餐?

I think:

- 宋耀 is a man's name,
- [一家](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%80%E5%AE%B6/) go together to form "household",
- I don't know what 如 is doing here (possible "like", as in "like a household"),
- [用过](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%94%A8%E8%BF%87) = used (past tense),
- [早餐](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%97%A9%E9%A4%90) = breakfast (but this seems mismatched with "used").

Or maybe [过早](http://%E8%BF%87%E6%97%A9) = premature.  I'm totally lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, it helps to know the names and background of the people you're reading about. The appearance of the name [宋慶齡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soong_Ching-ling) in the text should instigate an immediate background check.

- 宋耀如 is 宋慶齡's father - his proper name is [宋嘉澍](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Soong), and 宋耀如 is his [courtesy name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtesy_name).

> 一個星期天，宋耀如一家用過早餐，準備到一位朋友家去。
>
> *One Sunday, the house (family) of* 宋耀如 *had breakfast and planned to go to a friend's house*.

The *friend* should be primarily assumed to be that of 宋耀如, and by extension a family friend.

---

FYI: 用餐 is another way of saying 吃飯, if not a bit more old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

the problem you met is a common problem in Chinese, how to split a sentence into words(commonly known as tokenization in natural language processing). Actually, there are sometimes more than one way to split a sentence, such as 用过 and 过早 are both meaningful words, however, we would like to pick up the most probable way for splitting. In your case,  用过/早餐 is more often than 用/过早/餐. If you are not sure about your case, you may try some tools like https://www.toolnb.com/tools/fc.html.

Answer (score 0):

One sunday, 宋耀如's family is ready to go to a friend's house after finish their breakfast